# Get all messages from an OpenAI Thread

Tags: openai-api

I am approaching to get all the messages from a thread I started with OpenAI Playground.

I do get the list of messages from the API which includes everything within the limit of 100.

[https://api.openai.com/v1/threads/{thread_id}/messages?limit=100](https://api.openai.com/v1/threads/%7Bthread_id%7D/messages?limit=100)

I need the whole thread conversation and if I access the thread via browser it says:

[OPENAI MESSAGE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MLG8Q.png)

Via the api-call I only get the same as shown in the browser.

How can I get access to the messages before the cut off?

Thank you ind advance!

I tried to max out the range messages, but limit is 100.
It must give an answer to this, because of the shown message to access the cut of messages via api.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `after` query param to start at the next page.